# Django Model with custom string id field not being deleted

Tags: django, string, django-models, primary-key

I have a model with a custom string for an id.

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    id = CharField(
        max_length=23,
        auto_created=True,
        primary_key=True,
        serialize=False,
        verbose_name="ID",
        default=generate,
        editable=False,
    )
```

When deleting, I am getting this error.

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/sampleapp/user/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1988, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AC7EEKrEhYZ9p1r-Q'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    response = func(self, request, queryset)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\actions.py", line 39, in delete_selected
    ) = modeladmin.get_deleted_objects(queryset, request)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 2099, in get_deleted_objects
    return get_deleted_objects(objs, request, self.admin_site)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 120, in get_deleted_objects
    collector.collect(objs)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 186, in collect
    return super().collect(objs, source_attr=source_attr, **kwargs)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py", line 343, in collect
    field.remote_field.on_delete(self, field, sub_objs, self.using)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py", line 23, in CASCADE
    collector.collect(
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 186, in collect
    return super().collect(objs, source_attr=source_attr, **kwargs)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py", line 365, in collect
    sub_objs = field.bulk_related_objects(new_objs, self.using)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\fields.py", line 524, in bulk_related_objects
    return self.remote_field.model._base_manager.db_manager(using).filter(
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1071, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1089, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1096, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1502, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1532, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1448, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1273, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 276, in get_prep_lookup
    rhs_value = self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(rhs_value)
  File "path\to\sampleapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1990, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'object_pk' expected a number but got 'AC7EEKrEhYZ9p1r-Q'.
"POST /admin/sampleapp/user/ HTTP/1.1" 500 213503
```

Kindly help in solving this issue.

I first noticed this issue when attempting to delete via admin but that didn't work. Upon inspection, I noticed the issue was that the model could not be deleted even via shell.

Answer (score 1):

From your traceback:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AC7EEKrEhYZ9p1r-Q'
```

It's expecting an integer.
Is there a particular reason you want to replace the id field? You could always just create a separate field for your custom one and use that as the id elsewhere in your program

Comment: I wanted the id field to be a randomized string but I guess there is no way around it. The only issue comes in when deleting.